# How to clean up AJAX callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'd like to make an API call that prints out the values retrieved from 2 helper API calls.

See:

```
function api_call() {
  $.ajax({
      url: "...", 
      success: function (objects) {
          for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
              var id_1 = api_helper1(objects[i].id_1);
              var id_2 = api_helper2(objects[i].id_2);

              console.log(id_1 + id_2);
          }
      }
  });
}

function api_helper1(id_1) {
  $.ajax({
      url: "...", 
      success: function (value) {
          return value;
      }
  });
}

function api_helper2(id_2) {
  $.ajax({
      url: "...", 
      success: function (value) {
          return value;
      }
  });
}
```

The issue here is AJAX is async so api_helper1 and api_helper2 will run before console logs `id_1 + id_2`. What is the cleanest way to accomplish this without having multiple AJAX calls inside each other's success function?

Comment: Look at Promises and async/await, that might help you get what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with Promises:

```
function api_call() {
  return $.ajax({
      url: "...",
  });
}

function api_helper1(id_1) {
  return $.ajax({
      url: "..."
  });
}

function api_helper2(id_2) {
  return $.ajax({
      url: "..."
  });
}

api_call().done((objects)=>{
    for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
        $.when(api_helper1(objects[i].id_1), api_helper2(objects[i].id_2)).then((id_1, id_2)=>console.log(id_1 + id_2));
    }
})
```

Comment: How would I do this if I am dynamically appending HTML using the values returned from api_helper1() and api_helper2()?

Comment: @KevinB I'm not sure what you're meaning. If you want to append html to the DOM instead of printing the result to the console... just do it. jquerys `.append()` is your friend ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it with Promises

```
    $.ajax({
        url: '/getTag.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {tag:tag,docid:doc},
        error:function(err){
            reject(err)
        },
        complete:function(comp){
            let objects = JSON.parse(comp.responseText);

            for(var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++){
                apicall1(objects[i].id_1).then((id_1)=>{    
                    apicall2(objects[i].id_2).then((id_2)=>{
                        console.log(id_1 + id_2)
                    })
                })
            }
        }
    })


function apicall1(tag){
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/getTag.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {tag:tag},
        error:function(err){
            reject(err)
        },
        complete:function(comp){
            let jsons = JSON.parse(comp.responseText);
            resolve(jsons)
        }
    })
})
}

function apicall2(tag){
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/getTag.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {tag:tag},
        error:function(err){
            reject(err)
        },
        complete:function(comp){
            let jsons = JSON.parse(comp.responseText);
            resolve(jsons)
        }
    })
})
}
```

More info about how to use them
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise